# Kubernetes command and args syntax question

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run an nginx image as unprivileged, and found the following command stanza required to make this happen. I am NOT concerned with running the official nginx-unprivileged image, as that would defeat the purpose of the exercise (don't ask why...please).

Intended commands to convert from linux terminal style to Kubernetes YAML Pod manifest init-container section...

```
RUN sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
    && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    && chown -R 101:0 /var/cache/nginx \
    && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx \
    && chown -R 101:0 /etc/nginx \
    && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx
```

I have tried the following using block scalars to no avail...

```
...
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
args: 
- >
  sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
  && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && chown -R 101:0 /var/cache/nginx \
  && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx \
  && chown -R 101:0 /etc/nginx \
  && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx
...


...
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
args: 
- |
  sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf \
  && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
  && chown -R 101:0 /var/cache/nginx \
  && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx \
  && chown -R 101:0 /etc/nginx \
  && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx
...
```

Also using a single line...

```
...
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && chown -R 101:0 /var/cache/nginx && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx && chown -R 101:0 /etc/nginx && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx"]
...
```

None of these worked...the init-container never starts.

Here is another attempt...but the initContainer remains in a crashloopbackoff state...

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: securityreview
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 101
    runAsNonRoot: True
  initContainers:
  - name: permission-fix
    image: nginx
    command:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    
      fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    
      scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      && chown -R 101:0 /var/cache/nginx && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx
      && chown -R 101:0 /etc/nginx && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx
  containers:
  - name: webguy
    image: nginx
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 101
      runAsGroup: 101
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

Comment: can you add `error` from the `kubectl describe pod securityreview` ? also `kubectl logs securityreview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the following approach to separating multiple commands in a readable way:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
args:
  - >
    command1 &&
    command2 &&
    ...
    commandN
```

However, your case is more complicated, as running `sed`, `chown` and `chmod` commands without root privileges will result in a `Permission denied` error.

You can use an init container that shares a Volume with the nginx container.
The init container will run the `sed`,`chown` and `chmod` commands as `root` and then copy the modified files to the shared Volume that will be mounted and used by the nginx container. In this approach, you need a volume that init and application containers can use.
A similar use case can be found in the [Configure Pod Initialization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/#create-a-pod-that-has-an-init-container) documentation.

I will create an example to illustrate how it works.

---

As you can see in the code snippet below, I created the `permission-fix` init container that runs required commands and then copies modified files to the shared volume (`cp -Rp /etc/nginx/* /mnt/nginx-fix/`). The `webguy` container then mounts these files to `/etc/nginx`:

```
$ cat nginx-unpriv.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: securityreview
spec:
  initContainers:
  - name: permission-fix
    image: nginx
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
    args:
      - >
        sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf &&
        sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&
        sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&
        sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf &&
        chown -R 101:0 /var/cache/nginx &&
        chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx &&
        chown -R 101:0 /etc/nginx &&
        chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx &&
        cp -Rp /etc/nginx/* /mnt/nginx-fix/
    volumeMounts:    
    - name: nginx-fix
      mountPath: "/mnt/nginx-fix"
  containers:
  - name: webguy
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: nginx-fix
      mountPath: "/etc/nginx"
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 101
      runAsGroup: 101
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-fix
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
```

We can check if it works as expected:

```
$ kubectl apply -f nginx-unpriv.yml
pod/securityreview created

$ kubectl get pods
NAME             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
securityreview   1/1     Running   0          12s

$ kubectl exec -it securityreview  -c webguy -- bash
nginx@securityreview:/$ id
uid=101(nginx) gid=101(nginx) groups=101(nginx)

nginx@securityreview:/$ ls -l /etc/nginx
total 44
drwxrwxr-x 2 nginx root  4096 Jun 10 13:18 conf.d
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nginx root  1007 May 25 12:28 fastcgi_params
drwx------ 2 root  root 16384 Jun 10 13:18 lost+found
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nginx root  5290 May 25 12:28 mime.types
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nginx root    22 May 25 13:01 modules -> /usr/lib/nginx/modules
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nginx root   826 Jun 10 13:18 nginx.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nginx root   636 May 25 12:28 scgi_params
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nginx root   664 May 25 12:28 uwsgi_params
```

If this response does not answer your question, please provide more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: you're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The following file will run..but user 'nginx' still lacks the permissions; also the "&&" is not recognized by kubernetes.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: securityreview
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 101
    runAsNonRoot: True
  containers:
  - name: webguy
    image: nginx
    command:
        - "/bin/sh"
    args:
        - "-c"
        - |
          sed -i 's,listen       80;,listen       8080;,' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          && sed -i '/user  nginx;/d' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          && sed -i 's,/var/run/nginx.pid,/tmp/nginx.pid,' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          && sed -i "/^http {/a \    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp;\n    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;\n    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;\n    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;\n    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;\n" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          && chown -R 101:0 /var/cache/nginx
          && chmod -R g+w /var/cache/nginx
          && chown -R 101:0 /etc/nginx
          && chmod -R g+w /etc/nginx
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 101
      runAsGroup: 101
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```